# Rails Routing Error on static single image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting a rails routing error for a brand new image I just added. The other images in the folder all work perfectly (/public/images/%f requested at /images/%f) yet this one produces a routing error. I've checked file permissions and it's not that.

Anybody know what might cause this? I'm using the development env so caching is off and I've verified it is!

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: Is there any chance you could post, for instance, some failing view code?

Comment: It's a static image.... how could I have view code if there is no view....

Comment: 1) does the image really exist in the location you expected? 2) does the path contains any special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, rebooting my vagrant VM fixed it. Don't ask me why because I don't know and it doesn't make logistical sense, in the dev env everything should be reloaded on each request.

I did nothing else except boot the VM again after Zachary asked for some fail code and it was accessible as soon as rails loaded. I spoke to a colleague shortly thereafter and he too had a very similar issue where files were not accessible until after a reboot of the machine and similarly rebooting rails itself didn't do the same job for him either.

Sorry for wasting your time!